# When should I use SR, D, JK, or T Flip flops?

Tags: design, flipflop

In class I've learned about SR, D, JK, and T flip flops. From what I understand, you can construct any design by using any of them. So my question is when making a design, how does one choose which to use? Which one is used more in commercial circuits and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In discrete logic (like 74xx series), you use whichever choice lets you design your circuit with smallest number of parts and without violating timing requirements.

In FPGAs, you mostly design in HDL (VHDL or Verilog) and the synthesis tool works out for you what to use. But the underlying technology basically just provides D flip-flops, so the synthesis tool figures out how to implement what you code with D flip-flops.

In ASICs, a high level designer again designs with HDL. But probably (ASICs aren't my area) the ASIC vendor's library may provide other options beyond D flip-flops, and the synthesis tool will figure out how to implement the code using the available library components. It could choose one or the another to optimize either circuit speed or chip area.

Answer (score 4):

For simple designs, one type may have a clear advantage over the others depending on what you want to accomplish and the Flip-Flop's [truth table](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/logisim/docs/2.1.0/libs/mem/flipflops.html):

```
D Flip-Flop  T Flip-Flop  J-K Flip-Flop  S-R Flip-Flop
    D Q          T Q         J K Q           S R Q
    0 0          0 Q         0 0 Q           0 0 Q
    1 1          1 Q'        0 1 0           0 1 0
                             1 0 1           1 0 1
                             1 1 Q'          1 1 X
```

> **D Flip-Flop:** When the clock rises from 0 to 1, the value remembered by
>   the flip-flop becomes the value of the *D* input (*Data*) at that instant.
>
> **T Flip-Flop:** When the clock rises from 0 to 1, the value remembered by
>   the flip-flop either toggles or remains the same depending on whether
>   the *T* input (*Toggle*) is 1 or 0.
>
> **J-K Flip-Flop:** When the clock rises
>   from 0 to 1, the value remembered by the flip-flop toggles if the *J*
>   and *K* inputs are both 1, remains the same if they are both 0, and
>   changes to the *K* input value if *J* and *K* are not equal. (The names *J*
>   and *K* do not stand for anything.)
>
> **R-S Flip-Flop:** When the clock rises
>   from 0 to 1, the value remembered by the flip-flop remains unchanged
>   if *R* and *S* are both 0, becomes 0 if the *R* input (*Reset*) is 1, and
>   becomes 1 if the *S* input (*Set*) is 1. The behavior in unspecified if
>   both inputs are 1. (In Logisim, the value in the flip-flop remains
>   unchanged.)

Or, perhaps the [specific combination of gates](http://www.circuitstoday.com/flip-flops) may be of benefit to your circuit:

[image: S-R NOR]

[image: S-R NAND]

[image: S-R Clocked]

[image: D]

[image: J-K]

[image: T]

The SR Flip-Flop is the basic or the fundamental Flip-Flop. It is the simplest in that it has the lowest gate count. But it also has a state where the behavior is unspecified. Which could be bad if you have to design around it. Or it could be good if you want to exploit that unspecified behavior for some reason (though I can't think of one and the mention of it's usage in application has a "citation needed" in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_NOR_latch)).

However, as The Photon mentioned, FPGA slices are essentially Look-Up Tables (LUT), Multiplexers, Arithmetic Logic Units (ALU), and D Flip-Flops. Based on that, I would say that the D Flip-Flop is the most widely used in commercial circuitry due to their abundance in programmable logic.

[image: FPGA slice]

Answer (score 0):

Latching devices generally have three types of inputs: synchronous inputs, asynchronous inputs, and clock inputs.  Any device which has any synchronous inputs must have at least one associated clock input; the vast majority of devices which have synchronous inputs have exactly one clock input which is associated with all of them.

Each clock input is specified as operating on a rising edge, falling edge, or both.  If a clock input is specified as operating on the rising edge, that means that the device will be triggered if the input goes from low to high.  A device which is specified as operating on the falling edge, it will be triggered when the input goes from high to low.  A device which triggers on both types of transitions will trigger whenever the input changes state.

The state of a device may be affected any time its asynchronous inputs changes, but the only time synchronous inputs will affect the operation of a device is when the associated clock input is triggered.

The three most basic types of latching device are the RS latch *(sometimes called an RS flip-flop)*, the transparent latch, and the D-type flip flop.

An RS latch has two asynchronous inputs, R and S: when the R input is in its active state (some latches use active-high inputs, and some use active-low), the output will go low; when the S input is active, the output will go high.  When neither input is active, the output will remain high or low according to which input was last active.

A transparent latch has two asynchronous inputs, D and E.  When the E input is active, the state of the output will mirror the state of the D input.  When the E input is inactive, the output will hold whatever state it last held while E was active.

A D-type flip flop has a synchronous inputs D, and a clock input.  When the clock is triggered, the device will latch the state of the D input and, within a short time, start outputting the latched value.  The D input will be ignored at all other times.  Most types of flip-flop, other than the RS flip-flop (which in many cases really means "RS latch") have synchronous inputs which are named after the type of flip flop (e.g. a JK flip flop has J and K inputs).

While the first two devices above are entirely asynchronous, and the last one is completely synchronous, many flip flops include an asynchronous reset signal; any time that signal is active, the output will unconditionally be forced low, regardless of what the other inputs are doing.  Some also have an asynchronous preset which can force the output high.  Such devices will often be regarded as being synchronous if they are wired in such a way that (1) the reset signals will only trigger in response to a system-wide reset or other such event; (2) the reset signal will not change state near any active clock edge, unless such clock edge could be guaranteed not to cause the device to change state whether the reset signal was active or not.

Comment: j and k actually stand for the initials of the inventor, Jack Kilby

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is an older question but I still feel that it is current and relevant and I would like to reflect on this part of the OP's question:

> how does one choose which to use?

From my understanding is that the basic SR latch without a clock input is simply a latch. If you need to temporarily latch an output from some operation that isn't going to change that is also agnostic of any clock operations then an SR latch may be useful; however careful consideration needs to be taken into account when designing the circuit so that both the S&R inputs don't go high at the same time.

When the inputs are being latched synchronously based on a clock edge then your gated SR latches and DFFs are the most commonly used. So what about the JK and the T types?

Let's consider some different types of applications within hardware. If you are designing a cache model for a CPU and it needs to be readily available and fast you would probably want a gated SR latch or DFF depending on your design.

Now when it comes to different memory types agnostic of serial or parallel types, but as in ROM and RAM. Ram is usually slow as it comes across the bus so it has time before it's next I/O instruction is visible to it, so in the case of RAM a JK - Master Slave FF might be a viable solution however this dynamic type of ram is more expensive as each JK has a DFF as its master and a SR latch as its slave. So for each single bit of memory you have to latches or flip flops and you are almost doubling the amount of gates, but the memory is more robust and it is protected memory. You could use SR Gated Latches or DFFs within RAM to save space but when you do the memory is then static and it becomes volatile and you have to constantly refresh it.

Now if you are designing ROM which the CPU will fetch data from these types of registers for loading instructions sets, memory addresses and data contents here is where DFFs are most commonly used for their compact size and speed.

There is one type of FF that is left and that is the Toggle FF. So when would you want to use this type of flip flop?

With this type of FF you might use it when you are building Control Logic that decodes instruction sets. When a specific bit sequence comes in and you need to say set one line hi to perform an operation then disable it after the operation but before the next cycle is when you need to be able to toggle this control line on and off. So in this case there is where you probably want to use a T-Type because you want to be able to remember the state that it is currently in but also have the capability to change or toggle it so that it is ready for the next instruction cycle.

I'm self taught and this is what I have learned in the past few months and please correct me if you find kind of errors within my statements. Also if you would like an excellent explanation of these types of circuits you can always do a Youtube search for Ben Eater! He covers most of them, the only one that I think he doesn't go into too much is the toggle type, but then again when he is building the counters you sort of get an understanding of them.