# Is it possible to combine JK, SR and D filp flops in one circuit... and why?

Tags: digital-logic, design

I am taking a logic design class and the teacher asked this question.
I know I can use whatever I want in one circuit, I mean using JK then use SR in another part, but if I was to design a sequential circuit based on a ***state diagram***, let's say 4 states (2 flip-flops), is it possible to use on *SR* and the other is *JK*, or the circuit won't work ?

Comment: See related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48697/when-should-i-use-sr-d-jk-or-t-flip-flops/48769#48769

Answer (score 4):

Anything is possible if you define all the states, such as avoiding race conditions and include all combinational and sequential logic states if you define all the inputs. How many do have?

For a D, SR, & JK flip flop, input states, edge and level trigger must be included to become a well defined "register".  THere are more than 4 states such as race conditions. Normally the S input over-rides the Q output and the R over-rides the Q- output if you have two outputs.
This may help [expand some details.](http://www.iitg.ernet.in/asahu/cs221/Lects/Lec13.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can mix flip-flops as you want. Each will store one bit of your state. Typically you would use the same type for the whole machine only because they are bundled together in IC's. Eg. 4013 (2×D-type flip-flop), 4027 (2×JK flip-flop).